Symfony, Messenger, Kubernetes and messenger:stop-workers
My problem is as follows, I have a symfony application. It is dockerized in Kubernetes. One container is a web server, the second is consumer for symfony messenger and the third is symfony messenger consumer for symfony scheduler component. In my application, users can change certain scheduler parameters in the web, and for them to take effect I have to restart scheduler component. For this purpose, use the messenger:stop-workers command. Everything would work great if the processes were within one container. Well, they're not. What's the easiest way to handle this? I know not simple and inelegant methods based on creating a mechanism that restarts whole container. But maybe it can be done more nice and somehow inside symfony? some communication using shared cache/redis/db or sth?
In the case of a regular worker, I can send special messages forcing the entire worker to restart, but I don't think this can be done with a scheduler...?

You are correct. You can use a solution like Redis or a database table to manage the storage of the latest scheduler configurations efficiently.
Basically, each time a user modifies scheduler parameters via your web application, promptly record these changes. Then, configure the scheduler consumer to routinely check this shared data store for any updates. If it detects a newly updated configuration, the consumer should reload its scheduling parameters from this revised data.
